# C++ errors when compiling, error (unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++

I'm using visual basic 2010. I have tried everything I can think of to eliminate these errors. It's a simple idea behind the program but I'm curious if the issue has something to do with how I'm referencing or calling my variables. I an new to C++, any help or suggestions would be greatly received. Thanks in advance.

Box.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Box.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


double getVolume(int A, int B, int C){
double totalVolume;
totalVolume = A * B * C;
return totalVolume;
}
double getSurfaceArea(int A, int B, int C){
double totalSurface;
totalSurface = (A*B*2) + (B*C*2) + (A*C*2);
return totalSurface;
}
bool perfectBox(int A, int B, int C){
bool perfect;
if (A = B) 
    if (B = C)
        perfect = true;
    else
        perfect = false;
else
    perfect = false;
return perfect;
}
```

//Box.h

```
class Box
{
public:

int A, B, C;
Box(int A, int B, int C);

double getVolume(int A, int B, int C);
// get volume of entered sides


double getSurfaceArea(int A, int B, int C);
// calculate surgace are based on sides

bool perfectBox(int A, int B, int); 
// compare all 3 sides to determine if box is perfect

};
```

//Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Box.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Box::Box(int a, int b, int c){

}

int main()
{ 
int a, b, c;
cout << "Enter 3 side lengths of a box to determine volume, surface area and if it's perfect...
\n";
cout << "length of Side 1: ";
cin >> a;
cout << endl << "Side 2: ";
cin >> b;
cout << endl << "Side 3: ";
cin >> c;

Box test(a, b, c);
cout << "Total Area: " << test.getVolume(a, b, c) << endl;
cout << "Total Surface: " << test.getSurfaceArea(a, b, c) << endl;
cout << "Is it a perfect box: " << test.perfectBox(a, b, c) << endl;

system ("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: please include the error messages

Comment: Unresolved external symbol means you've declared something, used it, but not defined it - usually forgetting to link with a .obj file or import a .lib. Since you haven't shown the actual error we can't give you any further information.

Comment: Have you not heard of code indentation?

Answer (score 2):

You miss your namespace declaration.  When you refer to getVolume, it's not just getVolume, but Box::getVolume.

```
double Box::getVolume(int A, int B, int C){
double totalVolume;
totalVolume = A * B * C;
return totalVolume;
}
double Box::getSurfaceArea(int A, int B, int C){
double totalSurface;
totalSurface = (A*B*2) + (B*C*2) + (A*C*2);
return totalSurface;
}
bool Box::perfectBox(int A, int B, int C){
bool perfect;
if (A = B) 
    if (B = C)
        perfect = true;
    else
        perfect = false;
else
    perfect = false;
return perfect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please show the compiler output?
In your constructor you haven't assigned A, B, C so perhaps there is an issue there. Also you are using assignment operators i.e. =, not comparison operator i.e. == which are two different commands.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule: Every Function of class you want to use, must be declared [float functioName(int param)] in the .h file of the class. This includes the constructor classname(int a);

---

There is a missing constructor declaration in box.h

```
Box(int a, int b, int c);
```

should be move in box.cpp

```
Box::Box(int a, int b, int c)
{

}
```

Tip from a researcher of our computer science deparment:

first include system header then local headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Box.h"
```

instead of (different order depending on <> or ""):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Box.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
```

There also missing functions in the .h File. Every function which is defined in box.cpp must be declared in box.h

Declare:

```
float getVolume();
```

Define:

```
float Box::getVolume()
{
  float localVariableForVolume = A*B*C;
  //this works too float localVariableForVolume = this->A*this->B*this->C;
  return(localVariableForVolume);
}
```

Comment: I have overseen: You miss your namespace declaration. When you refer to getVolume, it's not just getVolume, but Box::getVolume.

Comment: You can edit your answer instead of posting comments